# validation engine popup not working on submit with html5 required

Tags: html, jquery-validation-engine

I am using html5 attribute 'required' in my form. Following are code snippets

```js
$('form').validationEngine('attach', {
  promptPosition: "centerRight",
  scroll: false,
  binded: false,
  onValidationComplete: function(form, status) {
    if (status == true) {

    } else {
      // foo; 
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/validationEngine.jquery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="nameIt1" name="nameIt" placeholder="Product name..." class="text validate[required] nameIt" required="required">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button yellow">
</form>
```

Here, the html5 native validation popup appears instead of validation engine popup. If I remove html5 attribute 'required' the code works properly.

Experts, please shade light on this.

Thanks in advance.

Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Actually if the main purpose of this code is to validate required text field your code works fine because I tested it already on my machine. The required attribute must be present in order to make that field native required html5. It's not even necessary to set that attribute to any value it should be only like this:

```
<input type="text" id="nameIt1" name="nameIt" placeholder="Product name..." class="text validate[required] nameIt" required >
```

And it will work just fine. If you remove that attribute the form will post back with the empty field from your specific code. But if you make some changes on your javascript function then you will notice the validation engine popup and in that case the required attribute is not required. See below here:

```
$('form').validationEngine('attach', {
    promptPosition: "centerRight",
    scroll: false,
    binded: false,
    onValidationComplete: function (form, status) {
        if (status == true) {
            form.validationEngine('detach');
            form.submit();
            alert('it is Ok');
        } else {
            alert('Not OK');
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this may help